# Converting ios project into android

Tags: c++, xcode5, cocos2d-x

I developed a game in ios using cocos2dx(c++) in xcode. Now i am trying to run that game in eclipse for android. so that i am running the ./build_native.sh file in terminal from proj.android folder. At the end of the build it is showing the following error.

```
/Users/srikanthreddy/Desktop/AndroidDev/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-                                                                                                                     androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux- androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/AppDelegate.o: in function AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching():jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp:57: error: undefined reference to 'SplashScreen::scene()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/Users/srikanthreddy/Desktop/AndroidDev/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/projects/New/proj.android'
```

I declared splashscreen.h in appdelegate.h & the game is start with splash screen. The game is running perfectly in ios.Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A similar answer is found here:
[Cocos2d-x: How to port a Cocos2d-x project developed with XCode to Android (via Eclipse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192058/cocos2d-x-how-to-port-a-cocos2d-x-project-developed-with-xcode-to-android-via?rq=1)

Have you got any .cpp or .c files inside the Classes directory? What the compiler needs to know is the location of these files; simply including the .h equivalent is not enough.

Inside proj.android/jni/Android.mk, observe the following entry (open in a text editor of your choice, such as textedit, or textwrangler):

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp
```

Now, look inside the Classes/ directory, and see what files. For me, I had my Molemio.cpp in there, and also specialLoad.cpp inside a folder called Load/

After seeing these files, I added to Android.mk, making the LOCAL_SRC_FILES part now look like:

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
               ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
               ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
               ../../Classes/Molemio.cpp \
               ../../Classes/Load/specialLoad.cpp
```

**Note that I added a backslash to the end of HelloWorldScene.cpp . This allows you to add a newline character without ending the list.**